# Use `LocalVolTermStructureHandle` in Python QuantLib

Tags: monte-carlo, quantlib, local-volatility

I would like to simulate a local volatility underlying
$$ dS_t = S_t\sigma(t, S_t)dW_t $$
and have looked at QuantLib's `LocalVolTermStructureHandle` to do so.

So far:

```
today = ql.Date().todaysDate()
calendar = ql.NullCalendar()
dayCounter = ql.Actual365Fixed()
spot = 100
rate = 0.0

initial_value = ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(spot))
flat_curve = ql.FlatForward(today, rate, ql.Actual365Fixed())

riskfree_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(flat_curve)
dividend_ts = ql.YieldTermStructureHandle(flat_curve)
```

Now, I have some Python-based implementation `localvol_func` of $(t, s)\mapsto \sigma(t, s)$ and would like to invoke

```
localvol_ts = ql.LocalVolTermStructureHandle(localvol_func)
```

(or similar) to finally do

```
process = ql.GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess(initial_value, dividendTS=dividend_ts, riskfreeTS=riskfree_ts, localVolTS=localvol_ts)
```

Does that make sense at all? Would this achieve what I'm trying to achieve?
I know Python QuantLib is just a wrapper, so most likely I cannot be working with a Python-based implementation of the local volatility function, right?
What would I need to do instead?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at line 64. C++ takes five inputs, so BlackVolTermStructure must be added.

https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/d0/da0/blackscholesprocess_8hpp_source.html

Answer (score 1):

As of QuantLib 1.30, you can sample your local volatility over a grid and pass the results to [the FixedLocalVolSurface class](https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/blob/QuantLib-SWIG-v1.30/SWIG/localvolatilities.i#L100).